# How can I recursively find folders containing a single file using batch?

Tags: batch-file

How can I use batch to find all subfolders in a directory that contains 1 and only 1 file with the file name which contains the word log and an excel file extension. Either xls or xlsx.

I tried to modify this batch script which finds empty folders and I think it's a good starting point but my batch skills are non-existent. I figure I need to add if statement to check if more than one file exist and if it does then ignore that direct. If only 1 file exist then I need to check to see if it contains Log in the name and has the extension xls or xlsx. I thing something like *Log*.xls* might work for the string comparison.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "myPath=%CD%"
for /r "%myPath%" /d %%F in (.) do dir /b "%%F" | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fF
```

For perspective here is why I want to do this. I have a co-worker whose job is to create all documentation. I noticed that he like to pull wool over our eyes by creating empty directories and directories with only a log file inside. There are hundreds of folder which should have assembly drawings and BOMs inside. It waste my time hunting for things that don't exist and so I want to compile a list so we can clean it up and deal with the problem. I know if there are more than one file in the directory there is a good chance the second file is the data I would actual want and the first file is the revision log.

EDIT to Show Example Folder Structures

I'm going to use BOM (bill of materials) as the example

```
BOM
└ BOM-1000
    └ [EMPTY]
└ BOM-1001
    └ Log.xls or Log.xlsx
└ BOM-1002
    └ Log.xls
    └ GoodData.doc or some other extension
└ BOM-1003
    └ SubfolderWithGoodData
    │    └ GoodData.doc or some other extension
    └ Log.xls
```

The first two example directories are what I want flagged. The last 2 contain a log and valid data and therefore shouldn't be listed in the output. There could possibly be one more scenario where there is a subfolder that should contain good data but instead it's just empty.

```
BOM
 └ BOM-1004
    └ SubfolderWhichShouldContainGoodData
    │    └ [EMPTY]
    └ Log.xls
```

Comment: What about this: `for /D /R %%D in (.) do @for /F %%C in ('dir /B /A:-D "%%~D\*.*" ^| find /C /V ""') do @if %%C equ 1 for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "%%~d\*log*.xls?"') do @echo "%%~D\%%F"`

Comment: Your question is currently too broad for our assistance. You've posted code which does not identify directories containing only one file, or one which even identifies those with only one file with an `.xls` or `.xlsx` file within them. In addition to that, you should be aware that the content of your target files are not plain text, so using `findstr` from a batch file probably wouldn't be the appropriate tool for such a task either.  As this site also does not provide code, or steps you through the process of writing it yourself, your question does not again, fulfil the site guidelines.

Comment: Re-reading the bottom section of your question, it appears that you may not in fact be trying to find text within an xls or xlsx file, but read from a revision log file. However, more confusingly, that file always sits along side one more, containing the data, you actually want. The confusion is that those directories must contain more than one file, because there must be at leat two files within those directories. You seriously need to [edit] your question, to clarify in simple terms exactly what you're trying to achieve, because currently your question is off topic as unlear too! Thank you.

Comment: What your latest edit now describes is a completely different scenario. It appears, _(best guess, as it's still unclear)_, that you're wanting a listing of all child directories only of parent _(`BOM`)_, which do not contain within them an Excel file _(`.xls`, or `.xlsx`)_, and at least one non Excel file, _(anything other than `.xls` or `.xlsx`)_; Or an Excel file, and a subdirectory with at least one non Excel file. Can you please confirm, or correct me? As this is a completely deiiferent scenario, I'm unsure whether we should look to modify our answers, or if you should post a new question.

Comment: Not exactly... The first part is accurate. If there is an empty child folder of the parent then that should be flagged as empty. The second part of your statement isn't correct. The second scenario which should be flagged is if there is only an XLS or XSLX file in the directory which contains the word log in its name.

Comment: If there is a second file in the child directory it can be named anything and have any extension. Most typically the extension of the second file in the child folder would be xls, xlsx, PDF, or doc. To restate, if there is one log file and a second file of any type no flag would be raised. The last scenario which would not be flagged is if there is one log file in the child directory but also a subfolder which contains any file type within the child directory.

Answer (score 1):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*"' ) DO (
 SET "nofiles=Y"
 SET "onefileonly=Y"
 FOR /f "delims=:" %%c IN ('dir /b /a-d "%%b\*" 2^>nul ^|findstr /n /R "." ' ) DO SET "nofiles="&IF %%c gtr 1 SET "onefileonly="
 IF DEFINED nofiles (ECHO No files IN %%b) ELSE (
  IF DEFINED onefileonly IF EXIST "%%b\*.xlsx" (ECHO Only one *.xlsx file IN Directory "%%b") ELSE IF EXIST "%%b\*.xls" (
  ECHO Only one *.xls file IN Directory "%%b") ELSE (ECHO Only one file IN Directory "%%b")
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Assign each directoryname in turn to `%%b`. Determine whether there are 0, 1, or more files in the directory by conducting a directory list and enumerating the resultant list. If there's exactly 1 file, determine its extension. Note sequence is important here, as a `.xlsx` file will likely have a shortname `.xls`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: Spoke too soon. I have a directory which has a file folder, and .xls file, and a pdf in it and it reports as only having 1 file. I'll see if I can debug it.

Comment: Odd. I've just tried exactly the same setup; a directory containing an empty subdirectory and two files, one `.pdf` and one `.xls` and for me, it reported just that the subdirectory was empty. I hope you've simply copy/paste/edited the code using a proper text editor.  I use [Editplus](https://www.editplus.com/) but there are others that a good Googling will find like `Notepad++`. `Notepad` is barely adequate as it tries to word-process code. Imprecise transcription is often the cause of such problems.

Answer (score 1):

As you did not clarify exactly what you required, I've had to take my lead from the other answer. This should therefore find every directory rooted from the location in `%sd%`, *(I've used `%CD%` to match your example, you can change that on line `2`)*, containing just one file, *(but any number of directories)*. If true, it will output a message for each of those which contains either a `.xls`, or a `.xlsx` file, telling you the full path of the directory and the name of the file.

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "sd=%CD%"
Set "fs=%__AppDir__%findstr.exe"
Set "ec=^" & For /F %%G In ('Copy /Z "%~f0" NUL') Do Set "cr=%%G" & (Set lf=^
% 0x0A %
)
Set "}=" & For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%cmd.exe /D/V/C
 "Dir "%sd%" /A:-D/D/S | "%fs%" /RC:"!ec! " | "%fs%" /RC:"!cr!!lf! *1 ""'
) Do If Not "%%H" == "" (Set "}=%%G" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F "Delims=" %%I In ('(Set PATHEXT^=^) ^& %__AppDir__%where.exe
    "!}:~-1!:%%H":"*.xls" "!}:~-1!:%%H":"*.xlsx" 2^> NUL'
    ) Do Echo !}:~-1!:%%H contains just one Excel file [%%~nxI]
    EndLocal)
Pause
```

*The last line is optional, if you intend to run the file from `cmd.exe`, as opposed to from the GUI.*

Comment: This code seems to work exactly how I described as does Magoo's code. However, I was wrong in my assumption of the folder structure for my specific situation. Unfortunately, some of the directories contain subfolders which contain the useful data. Let me see if I can explain. I'll edit my original question.